# Вывод двумерного vector< vector<int>>

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Почему все элементы выводтся в столбец. Если мы сначала в i кладем vector. А во вложенном цикле j это int;

```
int main(){
    vector< vector<int>> v;

    int n ;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < n ; j++)
            v.emplace_back(vector<int>()), v[v.size() - 1].emplace_back(j);

    for (auto i:v){
        for(auto j:i)
            cout << j << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод при n = 5:

```
0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
0 
1 
2 
3 
4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что вместо того, чтобы создать n векторов с n значениями, вы создали n х n векторов с одним значением. Поэтому код вывода и показывает n х n векторов с одним элементом.

Answer (score 1):

Перенесите создание внешнего вектора в первый цикл

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
 vector<vector<int>> v;
 int n = 2;
 for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
  v.emplace_back(vector<int>());
  for(int j = 0; j < n ; j++){
   v[v.size() - 1].emplace_back(j);
  }
 }

 for (auto i:v){
  for(auto j:i)
   cout << j << " ";
  cout << "\n";
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: а почему вместо v.size() - 1 не написать просто i ?

Comment: @KoVadim так у автора проблема не с этим

Comment: это понятно, у него проблемы глобальнее. Но не нужно писать переусложненный код. обычного push_back тут хватило бы за глаза.

Comment: Ну да, push_back чем emplace_back здесь было бы проще